# callbacks of androidx.media2 are not executed

Tags: android, androidx

In my music player demo, `MediaControler.skipToNextPlaylistItem()` result in more than one skip occasionally. The process as follows, in "12-30 19:46:20.248", the play auto change to 230 unexpectedly.

```
12-30 19:46:20.223 20440 20483 I MusicSessionCallback: onCommandRequest, command=10009
12-30 19:46:20.227 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onCurrentMediaItemChanged: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/344
12-30 19:46:20.244 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onMediaTimeDiscontinuity: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/344
12-30 19:46:20.245 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onMediaTimeDiscontinuity: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/344
12-30 19:46:20.245 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onBufferingStateChanged: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/344, state=2
12-30 19:46:20.248 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onCurrentMediaItemChanged: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/230
12-30 19:46:20.362 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onMediaTimeDiscontinuity: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/230
12-30 19:46:20.367 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onBufferingStateChanged: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/230, state=1
12-30 19:46:20.368 20440 20440 I MusicPlayerCallback: onMediaTimeDiscontinuity: mediaId=library://com.demo/local/song/230​
```

In my project:
`MediaLibraryService` is the playback service,
`androidx.media2.player.MediaPlayer` is the player,
`androidx.media2.session.MediaBrowser` is the callback of the service.

Answer (score 0):

Can not reproduce stably， when it happens，an extra callback of ExoPlayerWrapper$ComponentListener.onPlayerStateChange is called

```
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    : java.lang.RuntimeException: onMediaItemEnded: UriMediaItem{Media Id=library://com.demo/local/song/1249, mMetadata=Bundle[{android.media.metadata.ARTIST=久石譲, androidx.media2.metadata.BROWSABLE=-1, androidx.media2.metadata.PLAYABLE=1, android.media.metadata.MEDIA_URI=file:///storage/emulated/0/Music/music/%E4%B9%85%E7%9F%B3%E8%AE%A9-%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%B2%E3%82%99%E3%81%A8~memory~%20(%E5%85%A5%E6%AE%93%E5%B8%88~memory~).mp3, android.media.metadata.DURATION=250047, android.media.metadata.USER_RATING=Bundle[{a=androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl@8fd6716}], android.media.metadata.ALBUM_ART_URI=content://media/external/audio/albumart/33, android.media.metadata.DISPLAY_TITLE=おくりびと~memory~, android.media.metadata.MEDIA_ID=library://com.demo/local/song/1249, android.media.metadata.ALBUM=おくりびと OST}], mStartPositionMs=0, mEndPositionMs=576460752303423487}
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.player.ExoPlayerMediaPlayer2Impl.onMediaItemEnded(ExoPlayerMediaPlayer2Impl.java:754)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.player.ExoPlayerWrapper$MediaItemQueue.onPlayerEnded(ExoPlayerWrapper.java:962)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.player.ExoPlayerWrapper.maybeNotifyEndedEvents(ExoPlayerWrapper.java:668)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.player.ExoPlayerWrapper.handlePlayerStateChanged(ExoPlayerWrapper.java:528)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.player.ExoPlayerWrapper$ComponentListener.onPlayerStateChanged(ExoPlayerWrapper.java:682)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl$PlaybackInfoUpdate.lambda$run$5$ExoPlayerImpl$PlaybackInfoUpdate(ExoPlayerImpl.java:800)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl$PlaybackInfoUpdate$$Lambda$5.invokeListener(Unknown Source:2)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.BasePlayer$ListenerHolder.invoke(BasePlayer.java:177)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl.invokeAll(ExoPlayerImpl.java:811)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl.access$000(ExoPlayerImpl.java:49)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl$PlaybackInfoUpdate.run(ExoPlayerImpl.java:798)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl.notifyListeners(ExoPlayerImpl.java:711)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl.updatePlaybackInfo(ExoPlayerImpl.java:686)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl.handlePlaybackInfo(ExoPlayerImpl.java:630)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl.handleEvent(ExoPlayerImpl.java:573)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at androidx.media2.exoplayer.external.ExoPlayerImpl$1.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImpl.java:132)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
01-04 19:03:02.726 26640 26688 I XXXX    :  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
01-04 19:03:02.727 26640 26691 E XXXX    : 5 0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  library://com.demo/local/song/1249
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).